Issues connecting to SAP Hana Cloud DB for Vector embeddings
I've been following a blog on RAG with SAP HANA Cloud Vector Engine, GenAI Hub & CAP, pulled the Git Rep and following the instructions in the README.
The AI-Core part works fine and is connecting to my LLM but I'm having issues with my SAP HANA Cloud DB.
The CAP app runs fine, and it looks like everything is connected, but when I try to update the DB with the embeddings, I get:

[hana] - Error: Could not establish connection for tenant "undefined" due to error: No authentication method found

Any ideas?

As this question is specifically related to a blog in the SAP Community, I would recommend to also ask this question in the comments section of the blog as the author's insight may be helpful.

Hey thanks for trying out my blog post and checking out my code.
It seems like you have something mixed up with the HANA setup. It could be that the project is configured for Multitenancy which would mean that you need a tenant to onboard.
https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/guides/multitenancy/
You might want to check that and change the setup accordingly.
If you bind your SAP HANA Cloud instance to your local project setup, you can test things pretty easily.
I hope that helps, I would need to see your setup.

Hi Kevin.
Thanks for your response, the video was also useful in setting me on my way with this stuff.
It's not a multitenancy setup, although I'm using BAS on a Global account linked to a different Global account for SAP HANA Cloud and AI-CORE.
initially, as per the README, I created a SAP HANA Cloud instance pointing to our dev space. However, binding to this directly gave the above error

I then came across this tutorial https://developers.sap.com/mission.hana-cloud-cap.html and in particular these instructions on SAP HANA Cloud setup: https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hana-cloud-deploying.html
It turns out I need to create a single SAP HANA Cloud Instance pointing to 'Other Environments' rather than our dev space. This will allow the creation and binding of HDI containers in the CAP application.
Once I'd created the HDI Container/key in BAS, bound them and deployed, I was able to get the app working and view the HDI instance through the SAP HANA Database Cockpit.

I got there in the end, but may I suggest adding more info on the SAP HANA Cloud / HDI binding and configuration, or maybe like you say I'm missing something and should be able to connect to the SAP HANA Cloud instance directly rather than via HDI containers?
Anyway, thanks again, and looking forward to using the cap-llm going forward!

Another strange issue is when running with cds watch --profile hybrid.... I get srv/embedding-storage.cds:4:12: Error: Expected entity to have a primary key (in entity:“EmbeddingStorageService.DocumentChunk”) ... This is resolved by adding a Key of type UUID to the entity.

.... I also have to force a cd.connect.to('db') in the plugin to make the Rag and sim search work, but i'll post another question on that.

Interesting, glad you have run into these issues sharing them with me so I can improve the instructions. On the same time, I am sorry you have experienced so many issues. I will try to get all of that sorted out and documented.

@AdamHarkus would you mind opening an issue on the GitHub repository?
